# glassfish gem installation issue

Tags: glassfish, rubygems, jruby

When I do a `gem install glassfish`, I get an error:

```
"ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'glassfish' (>= 0), here is why:
          Found glassfish (0.1.2), but was for platforms universal-java-1.5 ,universal-java"
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have another (non-JRuby) ruby implementation installed locally, and the `gem` command you are running uses that other impl.  Run:

```
jruby -S gem install glassfish
```

Or, if you use rvm, switch back to a JRuby impl:

```
rvm jruby
gem install glassfish
```